# What are heap queues for?

Tags: python

Reading Guido's infamous answer to the question [Sorting a million 32-bit integers in 2MB of RAM using Python](http://neopythonic.blogspot.fr/2008/10/sorting-million-32-bit-integers-in-2mb.html), I discovered the module [heapq](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/heapq.html).

I also discover I didn't understand jack about it, nor did I know what I could do with it.

Can you explain to me (with the proverbial 6 years old target) what is the heap queue algorithm for and what you can do with it ?

Can you provide a **simple** Python snippet where using it (with the `heapq` module) solves a problem that will be better solved with it and not with something else ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`heapq` implements [binary heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), which are a partially sorted data structure. In particular, they have three interesting operations:

- `heapify` turns a list into a heap, in-place, in O(*n*) time;
- `heappush` adds an element to the heap in O(lg *n*) time;
- `heappop` retrieves the *smallest* element off the heap in O(lg *n*) time.

Many interesting algorithms rely on heaps for performance. The simplest one is probably partial sorting: getting the *k* smallest (or largest) elements of a list without sorting the entire list. `heapq.nsmallest` (`nlargest`) does that. The [implementation of `nlargest`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70ee0b76239d/Lib/heapq.py#l183) can be paraphrased as:

```
def nlargest(n, l):
    # make a heap of the first n elements
    heap = l[:n]
    heapify(heap)

    # loop over the other len(l)-n elements of l
    for i in xrange(n, len(l)):
        # push the current element onto the heap, so its size becomes n+1
        heappush(heap, l[i])
        # pop the smallest element off, so that the heap will contain
        # the largest n elements of l seen so far
        heappop(heap)

    return sorted(heap, reverse=True)
```

Analysis: let N be the number of elements in `l`. `heapify` is run once, for a cost of O(n); that's negligible. Then, in a loop running N-n = O(N) times, we perform a `heappop` and a `heappush` at O(lg n) cost each, giving a total running time of O(N lg n). When N >> n, this is a big win compared to the other obvious algorithm, `sorted(l)[:n]`, which takes O(N lg N) time.

Comment: Thanks. Though, I don't get how this is better than just holding the values in a collections.deque(maxlen=n) and if we encouter a value greater than the last one, just append() it.

Comment: Just checking whether the new value is greater than the last one in the deque doesn't give a correct algorithm (suppose n=2, the deque contains `[3,5]` and you encounter `4`). You'd have to do a sorted insertion into the deque at O(n) cost, yielding O(N×n) total running time.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that. Thank you for this precision.

Answer (score 2):

For example: you have a set of 1000 floating-point number.  You want to repeatedly remove the smallest item from the set and replace it with a random number between 0 and 1.  The fastest way to do it is with the heapq module:

```
heap = [0.0] * 1000
# heapify(heap)   # usually you need this, but not if the list is initially sorted
while True:
    x = heappop(heap)
    heappush(head, random.random())
```

This takes a time per iteration that is logarithmic in the length of the heap (i.e. around 7 units, for a list of length 1000).  Other solutions take a linear time (i.e. around 1000 units, which is 140 times slower, and gets slower and slower when the length increases):

```
lst = [0.0] * 1000
while True:
    x = min(lst)    # linear
    lst.remove(x)   # linear
    lst.append(random.random())
```

or:

```
lst = [0.0] * 1000
while True:
    x = lst.pop()   # get the largest one in this example
    lst.append(random.random())
    lst.sort()      # linear (in this case)
```

or even:

```
lst = [0.0] * 1000
while True:
    x = lst.pop()   # get the largest one in this example
    bisect.insort(lst, random.random())   # linear
```

Comment: Cool. I tried it and I do see that I can't find a better way to do it. But I don't understand why accessing the lowest / largest value in a heapqueue is that fast. Is it because their internals make it that way ? Doest it mean iterating / random access on it is slower ? What is the impact on memory consumption compared to other solutions ?

Comment: @e-satis [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) (as well as any algorithms textbook) covers the binary heap algorithms. Heaps don't provide random access at all (though the deletion algorithm can be generalized, keeping the O(lg n) guarantee). Memory usage is minimal: exactly the same as an array (Python's `list`).

Comment: As you can imagine, wikipedia is the first place I checked. But I'm not a math guy, and a dev to dev explanation feels much better to me.

Comment: A "heap" is just a Python list, kept in some clever order.  As long as you only use the functions heappush() and heappop() on it, then it is kept in this clever order, and heappush()/heappop() are crafted to work in logarithmic time.  That's basically all you need to know; you don't need to dive into how these functions work to understand how to use them.  Note that I cheated and didn't use heapify() in my example (because it's not needed in this particular case); fixed.

Comment: I like your answer almost as much as lasrman's. Sorry that I can't accept both.